# Работаю с модулем taggit (создаю теги на сайт в django) и выводит ошибку. Вот изображения

Tags: html, python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю теги для сайта добавил taggit в installed apps и pip install django-taggit прописал, но все равно не работает. Вот мой код

Данные с pip frezze

```
Warning: Could not parse requirement: -jango
Django == 2.2.3
django-gm2m==0.6.1
django-taggit==1.1.0
news==1.0
Pillow==6.0.0
pytz==2019.1
slugify==0.0.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: миграции применили после добавления `tags = TaggableManager()` ? а в `INSTALLED_APPS` добавили?

Comment: Вот хочу применить миграцию и вылазиет ошибка

Comment: Пришлите вывод pip freeze , чтобы убедиться в версиях пакетов

Comment: Извини что долго я добавил их в код

Comment: Замените изображения текстом.

Comment: Все изменил. В коде

Comment: @NeIT ошибку тоже нужно вставить текстом.

Comment: Все я решил проблемму

Answer (score -2):

Все, всем спасибо, я нашел ошибку. У меня django паленый, я перешел по папкам в документ related и отредактировал его код. Взял отсюда https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/ просто копировать вставить

Comment: вообще это делается через `pip uninstall django` и `pip install django`.